# How to make multiple IIS handlers, native and managed, work with Integrated mode

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-8.5

I created a native IIS module, called `MyModule`, that handles all requests (extensionless urls). For some requests, the native module needs to delegate the responsibility of handling the request to ASP.NET.

I managed to get this working with the following configuration in Classic Mode.

```
<system.webServer>
<handlers>
<add name="MyHandler" path="*." verb="*" modules="MyModule,IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
```

Notice how I specified two modules (comma separated). This enables both the modules to act as handlers for the request.

Is it possible to make this work using Integrated Mode? I am using IIS8.5 on Win2K12 R2.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/46c5ddfy.aspx

Comment: I need to handle all requests (wildcard) with one native handler, and if that fails, then with the asp.net managed handler. In the integrated mode, it looks like only one wildcard handler can be specified.